# Can't reach host on internal network

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openstack, netplan

I have 3 hosts running on the same Proxmox node with two network interfaces each. The first network interface on each node is on the 10.100.59.0/24 subnet with 10.100.59.1 being the default gateway and the second interface is on the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet with the former default gateway as well.

The problem is that all three hosts can ping and see each other on the 10.100.59.0/24 subnet but on the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet only two of the three nodes can see each other. The third one cannot be reached via this subnet from the other hosts but it shows up during an nmap scan of this subnet.

A couple of things to note:

1. Yes, the firewall is disabled on all three nodes.
2. Yes, I have checked for IP conflicts, there are none whatsoever.

Here are my netplan configuration files for each node:

node1:

```
---
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.100.59.215/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.100.59.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
    ens19:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  vlans:
    br-mgmt-vlan:
      id: 10
      link: ens19
    br-storage-vlan:
      id: 20
      link: ens19
    br-vxlan-vlan:
      id: 30
      link: ens19
  bridges:
    br-mgmt:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces:
        - br-mgmt-vlan
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.11/24
        - 10.0.0.12/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
    br-vxlan:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces:
        - br-vxlan-vlan
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.32/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
    br-storage:
      interfaces:
        - br-storage-vlan
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
    br-vlan:
      interfaces:
        - ens19
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
```

node2:

```
---
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.100.59.216/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.100.59.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
    ens19:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  vlans:
    br-mgmt-vlan:
      id: 10
      link: ens19
    br-storage-vlan:
      id: 20
      link: ens19
    br-vxlan-vlan:
      id: 30
      link: ens19
  bridges:
    br-mgmt:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.13/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
      interfaces:
        - br-mgmt-vlan
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
    br-storage:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.23/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
      interfaces:
        - br-storage-vlan
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
    br-vxlan:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.33/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
      interfaces:
        - br-vxlan-vlan
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
    br-vlan:
      interfaces:
        - ens19
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
```

node 3:

```
---
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.100.59.217/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.100.59.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
    ens19:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  vlans:
    br-mgmt-vlan:
      id: 10
      link: ens19
    br-storage-vlan:
      id: 20
      link: ens19
    br-vxlan-vlan:
      id: 30
      link: ens19
  bridges:
    br-mgmt:
      interfaces:
        - br-mgmt-vlan
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.14/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
    br-storage:
      interfaces:
        - br-storage-vlan
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.24/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 195.130.90.35
          - 195.130.90.45
    br-vlan:
     interfaces:
        - ens19
     parameters:
       forward-delay: 0
       stp: no
    br-vxlan:
      interfaces:
        - br-vxlan-vlan
      parameters:
        forward-delay: 0
        stp: no
```

nodes 1 and 2 can successfully communicate over either network interfaces, but node 3 can only communicate with the other two on the 10.100.59.0/24 subnet.

Comment: Why do you have **two** 10.0.0.0/24 subnets (mgmt and storage)?

Comment: @user1686 I haven't done such thing, there is only one such subnet. And even if I did have the same subnet twice I have segmented them with VLANs as you can see

Comment: It's two subnets _because_ it's on two different VLANs. The segmentation is precisely the problem; each host has two independent interfaces (belonging to different LANs or VLANs) that both have a route for the same /24. Which interface is shown by `ip route get 10.0.0.1` or `ip route show match 10.0.0.1` on all three hosts?

Comment: @user1686 pardon me, by your wording I thought you meant something else entirely. Yeah, there is the same subnet on a different VLAN just for the sake of consistency. On the problematic node 3 the `ip route get 10.0.0.1` gives `10.0.0.1 dev br-mgmt src 10.0.0.14 uid 0 \n cache`. On node 1 the result is `10.0.0.1 dev br-vxlan src 10.0.0.32 uid 0 \n cache` and on node 2 the result is `10.0.0.1 dev br-vlxan src 10.0.0.33 uid 0 \n cache`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have <del>two</del> three separate subnets that use the same subnet number. Both the "mgmt" VLAN and the "storage" VLAN – and upon closer look, even the "vxlan" VLAN on some hosts – are configured with addresses that belong to the same 10.0.0.0/24, *even though* they represent three isolated broadcast domains.

However, the subnets are not isolated the way you think, because all three `br-*` interfaces are still *on the same machine,* in the same network namespace, in the same VRF. Because you have multiple interfaces with the same prefix, and therefore three automatic "10.0.0.0/24" subnet routes, only one of them will be used for *all* addresses in the /24 (the OS doesn't attempt to "guess" from all three), and it's generally hit-or-miss as to which one will actually take priority.

Right now your checks show that on two hosts, the `10.0.0.0/24 dev br-vxlan` route takes priority, while the third host chooses the one via `dev br-mgmt`. (It will probably be different after a reboot.) The host can receive the inbound packets from other hosts, but most likely discards them due to "rp_filter" being enabled by default; and if the connections weren't as symmetric (e.g. not all hosts being part of the 'storage' VLAN) then the responses would be going the completely wrong way.

In short, do not use the same subnet number "for the sake of consistency". If the interfaces represent different broadcast domains, they need different subnet numbers as well.

---

In most cases, the only reasonable exception to this is the default IPv6 `fe80::/64`, which is considered to be "link scope" and on Linux requires the outbound interface to be explicitly specified as part of the address (though on Windows, the kernel *does* attempt to guess the interface by sending out NDP probes).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insight, but I can't understand the point of VLANs if I can't have two subnets with the same prefix length. Isn't that the point of VLANs? To separate a network into two or more separate networks, and hence being allowed to use the same network and subnet mask? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Losraio, VLANs are for separating a Layer2 network into separate broadcast domains. VLAN is a Network protocol, not an Internetwork protocol. IP networking (Layer 3) uses routers to communicate between L2 networks, but in order to do so, those networks must have unique IP range assignments so the routers can tell the networks apart, and route traffic between them, so in order for a VLAN to talk to another VLAN, there must be a router that will say "this came from .0.1/24 and is going to .1.1/24, so it goes out the interface that has the network .1.0/24 on it".

Comment: @Losraio: No, "…and hence being allowed to use the same network and subnet mask" does not follow from that. That's not part of the point of VLANs (nor of physical LANs – the point of VLANs is just to emulate separate physical LANs). On the contrary, it being two or more separate networks – which are still connected in the sense of having hosts and/or routers participating in both of them at once – means they need to have _different_ network numbers, so that there would be no ambiguity as to where each address is routed.

Comment: (You could theoretically have two VLANs (or two physical LANs) use the same subnet number if there weren't _any_ hosts or routers that would be attached to both of those VLANs at once, but it's very rare that this would be actually useful, or for that matter, usable without a huge headache.)

Comment: I'm still very confused, but other than that my problem is fixed, so thanks a lot for that. Guess I have to study networking a bit deeper...